# Filter variable and reorder its level with bar stacked plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a similar data frame:
Some unique objets have been created in different dates and were assigned codes for categorising.

```
  df <- data.frame(unique_num = c("A01","A02","A03","A04","A05","B01","B02","B03","C01","C02","C03","C04","C05","C06","D01","D02","D03","D04","D05"),
                   date = c(1983, 1986, 1986, 1984, 1986, 1983, 1984, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1983, 1983, 1986, 1987, 1987),
                   code = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "CC", "CC", "CC", "CC", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD")
  )
```

Need to focus on just onde code, filter it, and arrange the results with the general panorama.

```
  df %>% 
    group_by(unique_num, date, code) %>%  
    count(date) %>%  
    ggplot(aes(date,
               n,
               fill = ifelse(code == "BB", "", "blue"), 
               label = date, 
               group = date)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    theme(legend.position = "")
```

I'm getting close, I guess... but i want to organise the plot result having my highlighted results aligned in the bottom of the y axis.

How to reorder the stacked levels for the specified code?

The final result would have the coloured filtered code and at the base of the bar...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
df$code <- factor(df$code, levels=c("BB","AA","DD","CC"))  ## define order in the factor levels 
mycolor <- c("green","blue","red", "orange")


df %>% 
  group_by( date, code) %>%  
  count(date) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(date,
             n,
             #fill = ifelse(code == "BB", "green", "orange"), 
             fill = code,
             label = code, 
             group = code)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=mycolor) + labs(fill="code")
```

[image: output]